# Array merge solution

Tags: php, arrays

I have array

```
$data = array( 0 => array( "id"=> "2"), 1 => array( "idtes"=> "4") );
```

I want result

```
$result = array('id' => 2, 'idtes' => 4);
```

Comment: have you even searched? [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: Where's the other data or array?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how long the array will be:

```
$merged = [];
foreach ($data as $each) {
    $merged = array_merge($merged, $each);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-merge.php):

```
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$array_result = array_merge($array_one,$array_two);`